# Disabling Button Click According To Template IsEnabled Value

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, styles, controltemplates

I have a `Button` that I give it a control template style of a `CheckBox`.

See the following code:

```
<Style x:Key="radButtonCheakBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadButton}">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding ., 
Converter={StaticResource ContentConverter}}" 
Command="{TemplateBinding Property=Command}" 
IsEnabled="{Binding State,Converter={StaticResource CommandStateConverter}}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is that even when the `CheckBox` is disabled, and in the UI it is really disabled, 
the `Button` click still works, so when I press the disabled `CheckBox` I still get to the command.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried binding the Button.IsEnabled property too?

As an alternative - which I'd recommend - you can disable the command by implementing the CanExecute method so that it returns false whenever you want it disabled (probably the same logic you have located in your CommandStateConverter).

Comment: i binded the button isEnabled property to the same property and it worked well, i thougth that the button will autometicly will be binded to his template state( meaning the checkbox isEnabled value).

Comment: Nope, the template defines the contents of your customized Button. You could have several controls inside besides the CheckBox, some of them enabled and others disabled.